# Linq to sql questions‏

Tags: linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

i have some questions regarding linq to sql with c#. hope you can help...

1. Does creating Data base new DataContext load the entire DB to local cache every time?
2. If the answer is yes, Is there a way to Load Only the required part of the DB(with Querys Or Stored procedures maybe) to do so ?

3.Does Linq To Enteties is more suitable for this requirements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/ No, it does not load anything from the Database untill the query is executed

2/ ...

3/ You can load the entire database in Cache if you want to. BUt that has nothing to do with Linq-2-entities or Linq-2-sql. You can do it with either technology.